# How to get running total status counts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that keeps a history of task statuses. The status of a task can change over time and each time the status of a task changes a new entry is created in the table with the new status and the date modified.

Example:

```
Task ID| Status | Date Modified
-------+--------+---------------
100    |READY   | 2018-03-01
101    |READY   | 2018-03-01
102    |READY   | 2018-03-01
100    |RUNNING | 2018-03-02
101    |RUNNING | 2018-03-03
100    |FINISHED| 2018-03-03
102    |RUNNING | 2018-03-04
100    |READY   | 2018-03-04
101    |FINISHED| 2018-03-05
102    |FINISHED| 2018-03-07
```

How do I query a "running total" of status counts like below?

```
Date        | READY | RUNNING | FINISHED
------------+-------+---------+----------
2018-03-01  |     3 |       0 |        0
2018-03-02  |     2 |       1 |        0
2018-03-03  |     1 |       1 |        1
2018-03-04  |     1 |       2 |        0
2018-03-05  |     1 |       1 |        1
2018-03-06  |     1 |       1 |        1
2018-03-07  |     1 |       0 |        2
```

For example, on 2018-03-07:

- the status of Task 100 is READY (Last updated to READY on 2018-03-04)
- the status of Task 101 is FINISHED (Last updated to FINISHED on 2018-03-05)
- the status of Task 102 is FINISHED (Last updated to FINISHED on 2018-03-07)

So the status counts on 2018-03-07 are READY:1, RUNNING:0, FINISHED:2

I came across several running total examples on the web that use partition over, but I can't seem to apply those to this scenario.

Comment: A running total is usually calculated with respect to an ascending date. As date increases the value of a field is summed up to calculate the sum of all records *up to* to current date. Your sample data don't seem to demonstrate something similar to this.

Comment: It's not exactly a running total. But the idea is similar. On each date, I need the count of how many tasks are in each of the states. Since every task's status may not change every day, we need to look up the status updates for a task _up_ to the current date (in ascending order), to get the status counts for that date.

Comment: Can you explain how the count of each status is calculated for a specific date, e.g. `2018-03-07`? Also, why are your sample data listed in *descending* order?

Comment: Ah, I guess _ascending_ order in the example would have been better. But it doesn't really change anything.

On 2018-03-07:
- the status of Task 100 is READY (Last updated to READY on  2018-03-04)
- the status of Task 101 is FINISHED (Last updated to FINISHED on  2018-03-05)
- the status of Task 102 is FINISHED (Last updated to FINISHED on  2018-03-07)

So the status counts on 2018-03-07 are READY:1, RUNNING:0, FINISHED:2

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running total, you need the counts of the latest status for each ID?

Something like this should work, but you need a calendar table (a real one or a tally):

```
select
  c.date,
  sum(case when X.status = 'Ready' then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when X.status = 'Running' then 1 else 0 end),
  sum(case when X.status = 'Finished' then 1 else 0 end)
from
  calendar c
  outer apply (
    select ID, Status from
    (
        select
            ID,
            row_number() over (partition by ID order by DateModified desc) RN
        from
            yourtable t
        where
            t.DateModified <= c.date
    ) X
    where X.RN = 1
  ) X
group by
  c.date
```

This gathers latest status for each of the IDs for each day and then calculates the counts. There might be syntax errors, but something like this should work.

Comment: Worked for me. [SQL Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/860868/how-to-get-running-total-status-counts-in-sql-server)